# Order of root of unity in a completion

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a number field and $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime. Is it true that the order of a root of unity in the completion $F_\mathfrak{p}$ divides $N\mathfrak{p}$? I think it’s true for the Hensel’s lemma but I would like some confirmations or an idea of the proof.

Comment: please add more information, what have you tried

Comment: It’s only an idea: I would like to generalize the fact that it’s true when $F=\mathbb{Q}$ and that proof uses the Hensel’s lemma

Comment: I mean [ex 4.2, pag 4] https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.299.1027&rep=rep1&type=pdf …I’m pretty sure that one can generalize, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not even true for $F = \mathbf{Q}$ for any prime $p > 2$. The order of any root of unity in $\mathbf{Q}_p$  for $p$ odd divides $p-1$, and the norm of $p$ is $p$.

Another counter-example. If $F = \mathbf{Q}(\zeta)$ where $\zeta$ is a $p^n$th root of unity, then $\mathfrak{p} = (1 - \zeta)$ has norm $p$. But the roots of unity in $F_{\mathfrak{p}}$ clearly contain $\zeta$ and so can have order at least $p^n$.

Some exercises:

1. The group of roots of unity in $F_{\mathfrak{p}}$ of order prime to $p$ is cyclic of order $N(\mathfrak{p}) - 1$.
2. The group of $p$-power roots of unity in $F_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is trivial unless the ramification degree $e$ of $\mathfrak{p}$ satisfies $e \ge p -1$. In particular, if $p$ is odd and $\mathfrak{p}$ is unramified, or if $p$ is any prime but $p > 1 + [F:\mathbf{Q}]$, then there are no $p$-powered roots of unity in $F_{\mathfrak{p}}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!